# WPF Datagrid lost focus when refresh my collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, collectionviewsource, lostfocus

When key press "F5"

I refresh my collection `colecao.View.Refresh();`

...and lost focus of my datagrid

To back focus in row of datagrid I try this:

1. `Focus()` on datagrid
2. `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement`
3. `row.Focus()`
4. ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using a CollectionView, I think you have to move the current selection using `view.MoveCurrentTo(object)` or similar function.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find others, like `view.MoveCurrentToFirst()`, etc.

Comment: I use you example to way of my solution:
on Up key:
 colecao.View.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
 gradeDados.ScrollIntoView(gradeDados.Items[gradeDados.SelectedIndex + 1]);

on Down Key:
  colecao.View.MoveCurrentToNext();
  gradeDados.ScrollIntoView(gradeDados.Items[gradeDados.SelectedIndex + 1]);